# how to split a list in to different strings in python

Tags: python, list, split

i have a list object like this

`value = [<employee 'Mark Twain' as 'Captain'>,<employee 'Huckle' as 'Cowboy'>]`

now i would like to have the employee and  in a seperate variable like emplo[0] and as[0] like

```
emplo[0] = 'Mark Twain'
as[0] = 'Captain' 
emplo[1] = 'Huckle'
as[1] = 'Cowboy'
```

from the value maybe loop through the list and return the value

is there any possible code to split the list value in seperate variables?

Comment: Are those two `<emplo..` strings?

Comment: Your `value` is invalid Python literal. Can you show us exact what input are we dealing with?

Comment: It depends on the exact implementation of the objects in your `value` list. Where do those objects come from?

Comment: What you want to do is probably somewhat easy, though you haven't specified your problem clearly enough. Also -- don't use `as` as a variable name.

Comment: hi there the list  is a sample and comes from python tmdb3 Module and was fetches from movie object like
`result=searchMovie(line)
 value = result[0].cast`
       
 
i wish to store cast value and as value in seperate variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to access the objects' data based on the methods those objects implement or reading whatever their attributes are. But in the absence of other information you *could* split these up assuming that none of the names or jobs ever contain a `'`.

When you print

```
value = [<employee 'Mark Twain' as 'Captain'>,<employee 'Huckle' as 'Cowboy'>]
```

that's the `repr` result of each object, so you could call `split` on that in two list comprehensions:

```
employees = [repr(obj).split("'")[1] for obj in value]
positions = [repr(obj).split("'")[3][:-1] for obj in value]
```

`repr(value[0])` will produce `<employee 'Mark Twain' as 'Captain'>`, so when you call `split("'")` on that you get a list like this:

```
['<employee ', 'Mark Twain', ' as ', 'Captain>']
```

So calling `[1]` on that result gets the employee name, and calling `[3]` will get their job, though you'll also need to slice the last character off that string as it has `>`, that's why I added `[:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `employees` are class objects, something like below

```
class Employee(object):
    name = ''
    nickname = ''

emplo = [employee.name for employee in employees]
nickname = [employee.nickname for employee in employees]
```

or in 1 loop

```
emplo, nicks = [], []
for employee in employees:
    emplo.append(employee.name)
    nicks.append(employee.nickname)
```